# Vectors and Matrices how to solve

Tags: vectors

Let Π1, Π2 and Π3 be the planes with Cartesian equations  + 2 + 3 = 5,  −  + 2 = 7 and 3 − 3 + 9 = 10 respectively, where  is a constant.

(i) Find  given that Π1, Π2 and Π3 do not have a unique point of intersection.

Answer k = 2/3

Comment: What are you allowed/expected to use to solve this problem? There are several possible approaches. Presumably this is an exercise that you’ve been given as part of some course, so what is it that you’re studying? The tag “vectors” doesn’t really narrow it down much. For instance, if this is part of a linear algebra course, you’re probably expected to row-reduce the coefficient matrix of this system of equations and/or examine a determinant instead of, say, bashing out a solution algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation we get
$$x=5-2y-3z$$ plugging this in the second equation we obtain
$$9y+18z=5$$
and from the third equation (with the $x$ above) we have
$$z(2-3k)-y(1+2k)=7-5k$$
plugging $$z=\frac{5}{18}-\frac{1}{2}y$$ in the last equation above:
$$(\frac{5}{18}-\frac{1}{2}y)(2-3k)-y(1+2k)=7-5k$$
simplifying we obtain
$$-{\frac{67}{9}}+{\frac {17\,k}{3}}+2\,y-3\,yk-y \left( 1+2\,k \right) =0$$
Can you finish?
Simplifying this we get
$$(-3+k)y=\frac{67}{9}-\frac{17}{3}k$$